# GCC undefined reference to thrd_create() in C11 mode after #include <threads.h> in Debian

Tags: gcc, debian, c11, threads.h

I'm trying to compile a program that I've been able to compile on several other Debian environments with no issues using the C11 `<threads.h>` library on a relatively fresh install of Debian Bullseye with "`gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110`" installed

with the command

`gcc -o <progname> -O3 -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -lpthread <sourcefile>`

and I'm getting a string of linker errors in the form of
`undefined reference to 'mtx_unlock'`
as well as `mtx_lock` `mtx_init` `thrd_create` etc.

But I'm not getting an error saying the `threads.h` file is absent. I tried removing the `-lpthread` argument from the compilation command but this changed nothing.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command line parameter seems to be `-pthread` without the `l`.